# Separate GUIDs in Generic classes in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I've created the following class:

```
[Guid("4469031d-23e0-483c-8566-ce978ccc9a6f")]
class MyGenericContianer<BasicType> : SomeOtherContainer
{
}
```

This causes the folowing two classes to have the same GUID:

```
MyGenericContianer<int> x;
MyGenericContianer<float> y;
```

I need each specific type to have it's own GUID. How would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to do this with inheritance.

```
class MyGenericContianer<BasicType> : SomeOtherContainer { }

[Guid("4469031d-23e0-483c-8566-ce978ccc9a6f")]
class Container1: MyGenericContainer<X> { }

[Guid("5569031d-23e0-483c-8566-ce978ccc9a6f")]
class Container2: MyGenericContainer<Y> { }
```